# .NET MVC Web API Upload file to local storage and data model to database

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I want to upload a file and pass the model with it. But when I try it from postman, it Always bring error.

Here is my code

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostArPumPd([FromBody] tx_arPumPd pum)
    {          
        try
          {
            if (pum == null)
            {
                return Content(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Enter the data correctly");
            }
            else
            {
            tx_arPumPd arpumpds = new tx_arPumPd()
            {
                doc_no = doc,
                doc_date = DateTime.Now,
                descs = pum.descs,
                currency_code = pum.currency_code,
                amount = pum.amount,
                employee_code = pum.employee_code,
                head_code = pum.head_code,
                company_code = pum.company_code,
                created_by = pum.emp_code,
                created_date = DateTime.Now
            };
            db.tx_arPumPd.Add(arpumpds);

            var multiFormDataStreamProvider = new MultiFileUploadProvider(Constants.MEDIA_PATH);                   

            var mod = "PP";
            var newFileName = mod + "_" + doc;

            await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(multiFormDataStreamProvider);

            try
            {
                await FileHelper.Upload(multiFormDataStreamProvider, mod, newFileName);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return Content(HttpStatusCode.Created, "Data was save");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Content(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex);
            }                    
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Content(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex);
    }
}
```

I get an Error while i get to this part
await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(multiFormDataStreamProvider);

This is the error

> ioexception: unexpected end of mime multipart stream. mime multipart
>   message is not complete test with postman

Is there anyone who know why? And Help me to upload file and the data model?
Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Can you share the full and exact error message? Please add it to your question

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found the answer. To save a file and the Form data, i'm not parse the model. I'm just send the data from postmant using form data and the value is Json data. So I read the request from ReadAsMultipartAsync and get the Json data, and then deserilize the json. After that we can save the data.

This how I send the data from postmant
[Postmant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vc2fL.png)

and this is the code

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostArPumPd()
    {          
        try
          {
            var multiFormDataStreamProvider = new MultiFileUploadProvider(Constants.MEDIA_PATH);
            var readToProvider = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(multiFormDataStreamProvider);

            // Get Json Data and Deserialize it
            var json = await readToProvider.Contents[0].ReadAsStringAsync();
            tx_arPumPd a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<tx_arPumPd>(json);

            // Set mod and file name for FileHelper classl
            var mod = "PP";
            var newFileName = mod + "_" + doc ;

            tx_arPumPd arpumpds = new tx_arPumPd()
            {
                doc_no = doc,
                doc_date = DateTime.Now,
                descs = a.descs,
                currency_code = a.currency_code,
                amount = a.amount,
                employee_code = a.employee_code,
                head_code = a.head_code,
                company_code = a.company_code,
                created_by = a.emp_code,
                created_date = DateTime.Now
            };
            db.tx_arPumPd.Add(arpumpds);

            var dtl = a.tx_arPumPdDtl;

            foreach (var item in dtl)
            {
                item.doc_no         = doc;
                item.bg_is_ok       = true;
                item.bg_approved    = true;
                item.bg_app_date    = DateTime.Now;
                item.created_by     = a.emp_Code;
                item.created_date   = DateTime.Now;
                db.tx_arPumPdDtl.Add(item);
            }

            try
            {
                await FileHelper.Upload(multiFormDataStreamProvider, mod, newFileName);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return Content(HttpStatusCode.Created, "Data was save");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Content(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex);
            }                    

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Content(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex);
        }
    }
```

if anyone has a better way to do this, i'm still very happy getting to know about it.
Thank you.